# Special Power Set that does not contain "mixing" of subsets.

Tags: combinatorics

Say I have a set $G = \{ A, B, C, D, E...\}$ where all elements $A,B,\ldots$ are sets containing $k$-tuples of size $2$. For further notation, $A = [a1, a2,...ak]$.

Now I would like to generate a powerset of G, let's denote it H, such that
$H = \{ \{A,B\}, \{A,C\}, \{A,D\}, \{A,E\}, \{B,C\}, \ldots, \{A,B,C,D,E,\ldots \}, \ldots\}$.

This - to my knowledge - does not coincide with a normal powerset, as I do not want to mix up the elements inside $A$ and $B$. For example, I do not want $[a1, a2, ... a{k-1}, bk] \in H$.

How would I properly define $H$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the normal power set $H = 2^G$ works fine. The power set of $G$ only "looks" at the elements inside $G$ (that is, your sets $A, B, C, D, E, \ldots$ in this case), not "inside" those elements.

Comment: Oh really? How would I then define a power set that also looks "inside" those elements? With $P(\cdot)$ being the power-set operator, $P(P(A),P(B),...P(Z))$?

Comment: @FooBar:  What do you want to do with the powersets of the elements of $G$?  If you just want the union of them, you can say $\cup_{i \in G}P(i)$, for example.

Comment: @FooBar: Or perhaps you want the powerset of the union of the members of $G$, i.e. $P(\bigcup G) =$ $P(A \cup B \cup C \cup \dotsb)$? This will contain all sets containing any combination of members of any of your sets $A$, $B$, etc.

Comment: Very good, Ilmari, that exactly was the second thing I needed. Thanks guys.